# question..how can i get my firebase array of items to display in my swiftui list in order by date/time?

Tags: firebase, listview, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

[image: My Firebase item "Date" is shown]

[[image: Screen to display list is out of order]]

//Here is my fetch statement, and you can see i tried this "order(by: "Date"). didnt work.

```
    func fetchTechPapers(_ meet: Meeting){
    let uid = meet.uid
    FirestoreConstants.MeetingsCollection.document(uid).collection("Technical").order(by: "Date", descending: false).getDocuments{ documentsSnapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            self.errorMessage = "Failded to fetch contacts: \(error)"
            print("Failded to fetch contact: \(error)")
            return
        }
        documentsSnapshot?.documents.forEach({ snapshot in
            let paper = try? snapshot.data(as: BreakOuts.self)
            self.papers.append(paper!)
        })
    }
}
```

//Here is the list for my view:

```
                List{
                ForEach(vm.papers) { paper in
                    ZStack{
                        NavigationLink(value: paper) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }.opacity(0.0)
                        
                        PapersRowView(paper: paper, viewModel: vm)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear(perform: {
                })
            }
```

Any ides or direction to where i could go to read how this is done id appreciate it.

Comment: You should use a standardized date format that includes timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Date` field in your database holds a string value, and (as shown in the documentation on [data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#data_types)) Firestore orders string values lexicographically. In that order, your `"12/20/2023 6:00pm"` value comes *after* `"11/21/2024 8:05pm"`. Chronologically that's not correct, but since these are strings it's what ends up happening.

There is no option to have the database chance it's sort order to accommodate your use-case. Your options are to:

- Store the value as an actual `Date` or `Timestamp` value, which ensures that Firestore then orders them chronologically.
- Store the value in a string format that allows sorting the way you'd want, such as `"2023/12/20 18:00"`. For more such formats, see [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).